# How to remove an element from List of Widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I made a list of TableRows in flutter whichI passed as a children to my Table widget .Each row has some data and a flat button at the end which deletes the data from by database and I want to delete it from that list of TableRows also on the go .I know i have to use change the whole list under setState function but its not actually happening. What happens is it deletes from the database but the my UI remains same but when i go to previous screen and come back to that then its not there .So basically i able to delete it from database but not from UI

```
class _DataPreviewScreenState extends State<DataPreviewScreen> {
  List<TableRow> listView = [];
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    finalData = widget.data; //<- final data is my data from Database its actually a Map<String,dynamic>
    listView=listCreater();
  }

  List<TableRow> listCreater() { //<-here im am making the list of TableRow Widgets
    List<TableRow> list = [
      TableRow(
        children: [
          RowHead(heading: 'Site'),
          RowHead(heading: 'UserName'),
          RowHead(heading: 'Password'),
          RowHead(heading: ' '),
        ],
      ),
    ];
    var i;
    for (var data in finalData) {
      var item = TableRow(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.rectangle),
        children: [
          RowCell(data['site_name']),
          RowCell(data['user_name']),
          RowCell(data['password']),
          Container(
            height: 35.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {   //<- removing That particular list item from database
                DataModel.instance.delete(data['_id']);
                setState(() {
                  listView.removeAt(i);   /<-trying to delete from UI
                });
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.delete,
                size: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
      list.add(item);
      i++;
    }

    return list;
  }
```

Place where i'm passing the rows

```
Container(
  child: Table(
    columnWidths: {3: FractionColumnWidth(0.1)},
    children: listView,
  ),
),
```

How the Ui looks currently

[image: Thats how the UI looks]

please help me with the problem or give me any reference to the article or something about keys or any suggestion in my logic like whats the common practise to do it or something.
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to remove directly items from the UI, you should instead delete the element from the list and your widget depend on the data.

However, you are missusing the StatefulWidget here.

In general, when we use a StatefulWidget, we fetch the data in the didChangeDependencies() method and update this data in the setState((){}) method. Calling setState() will rebuild the UI (which is cheap) based on the updated data.

Here, your widget data depends on its parent, so :

- either you have a Stateless widget which depends on the data of its parent, and when the parent data changes, you call setState() on the parent which will rebuild the child with the new data,
- or you have a StatefulWidget which retrieves the data and updates it in the setState() method.

**For instance:**

In your `didChangeDependencies()` method :

```
_myDataList = DataModel.instance.getMyData();
```

in your `Build()` method :

```
Container(
              child: Table(
                columnWidths: {3: FractionColumnWidth(0.1)},
                children: listCreater(),
              ),
            )
```

And your `listCreater()` method :

```
List<TableRow> listCreater() {
    return [
      TableRow(
        children: [
          RowHead(heading: 'Site'),
          RowHead(heading: 'UserName'),
          RowHead(heading: 'Password'),
          RowHead(heading: ' '),
        ],
      ),
      for (var data in myDataList) 
       TableRow(
        key: UniqueKey(), // This is probably not usefull
        decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.rectangle), // BoxShape.rectangle is the default value, you can also eventually remove this line
        children: [
          RowCell(data['site_name']),
          RowCell(data['user_name']),
          RowCell(data['password']),
          Container(
            height: 35.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                DataModel.instance.delete(data['_id']);
                setState(() {
                  myDataList.removeWhere((e)=>e.id == data.id);
                });
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.delete,
                size: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )

    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listView.removeAt(i);
```

This line is the source of many errors. Whenever you will fix one, another one will pop up. For starters, you never initialized `i`. But do not go there. This is a rabbit hole. Removing from that list based on an index that was correct at some time in the past is a fools errand.

Use `removeWhere` instead and find the correct row by using data (maybe you have an id?), not just an index.

Generally speaking, the concept is to hold the data and rebuild the view. Rebuilding the view is relatively cheap. Removing from the data is easier to accomplish because you have... well... the data at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need a `StatefulWidget` for your `DataPreviewScreen`.

Instead, you should get the data from your `DataModel` that, I suppose, is some kind of `Provider`.

Here is an example using [Flutter Hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) and [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages?q=riverpod):

[image]

My `dataProvider` provides both the State (a List<Map<String, dynamic>>) and the functionality to delete an entry. I listen to the State in my `AppWidget` and feed the data to `DataPreviewScreen`, a pure `StatelessWidget`.

When the user clicks on a delete button, I ask my `dataProvider` to delete it and then the new State flows in.

### Full source code for easy copy-paste

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:faker/faker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: AppWidget()));
}

class AppWidget extends HookWidget {
  const AppWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final data = useProvider(dataProvider.state);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: DataPreviewScreen(data: data),
    );
  }
}

class DataPreviewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> data;

  const DataPreviewScreen({Key key, this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Table(
          columnWidths: {
            0: FlexColumnWidth(4),
            1: FlexColumnWidth(4),
            2: FlexColumnWidth(2),
            3: FlexColumnWidth(1),
          },
          children: [
            TableRow(
              children: [
                RowHead(heading: 'Site'),
                RowHead(heading: 'UserName'),
                RowHead(heading: 'Password'),
                RowHead(heading: ' '),
              ],
            ),
            ...data
                .map(
                  (item) => TableRow(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    children: [
                      RowCell(item['site_name']),
                      RowCell(item['user_name']),
                      RowCell(item['password']),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () =>
                            context.read(dataProvider).delete(item['_id']),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.delete,
                          color: Color(0xFF9F1D35),
                          size: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RowHead extends StatelessWidget {
  final String heading;

  const RowHead({Key key, this.heading}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 36.0),
      child: Text(
        heading,
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RowCell extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const RowCell(this.text, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(child: Text(text));
  }
}

final dataProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<DataNotifier>((ref) => DataNotifier());

class DataNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> {
  DataNotifier([List<Map<String, dynamic>> state]) : super(state ?? dummyData);

  delete(String id) {
    // delete from database
    state = state.where((item) => item['_id'] != id).toList();
  }
}

final faker = Faker();
final dummyData = List.generate(
  20,
  (index) => {
    '_id': 'id_${faker.randomGenerator.string(6, min: 6)}',
    'site_name': faker.company.name(),
    'user_name': faker.person.name(),
    'password': faker.randomGenerator.string(8, min: 8),
  },
);
```

### Remarks

- You should probably define a clear Entity for your Data instead of using a Map<String, dynamic> type. Have a look at [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed).
- Instead of listening to the State in `AppWidget`, `DataPreviewScreen` could also be a HookWidget and both listen to and use the `dataProvider`.